# iOS: filling tableView from SQLite database

Tags: ios, sqlite, uitableview, exc-bad-access, sigabrt

I'm trying to fill a tableView with info extracted from an SQLite database... I've read some tutorials and tried to follow them, but for some reason, my app keeps crashing...

.h

```
//
//  InOrder.h
//  AGKUnsten
//
//  Created by Jonas Christensen on 7/12/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface InOrder : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

    NSArray *artworkInfo;
    int rowsInDatabase;
}
```

.m

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *artworkInfo;

@end


//
//  InOrder.m
//  AGKUnsten
//
//  Created by Jonas Christensen on 7/12/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "InOrder.h"
#import "ArtworkView.h"
#import "PaintingInfo.h"
#import "PaintingDatabase.h"

@implementation InOrder

@synthesize artworkInfo;

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return rowsInDatabase;
    //return [artworkInfo count]; //Tried to use this, but app just crashes when it reaches this line
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSLog(@"test");//To see how far I get in the code - this is outputted
    //Configure the cell

    //APP CRASHES IF I TRY TO DO SOMETHING WITH MY DATABASE IN HERE

    //cell.textLabel.text = [artworkInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//Tried this

    //PaintingInfo *info = [artworkInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//Tried this
    //cell.textLabel.text = info.artist;

    //[[cell textLabel] setText:[artworkInfo objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];//Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT"

    NSLog(@"test2");//Never reach here if I uncomment any of the above

    return cell;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.title = @"Værker";

    artworkInfo = [[PaintingDatabase database] findAllArtists];

    rowsInDatabase = [artworkInfo count];
    NSLog(@"%d", rowsInDatabase);

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...
I know my database works, as I'm able to get data from it elsewhere, but it seems that when I try to use it here, the app just crashes...

It's mainly EXC_BAD_ACCESS and SIGABRT that get's displayed as the error...

Now, I've been told that SIGABORT = "SIGABRT is the signal sent when the program is attempting to abort itself. Generally this is because something really bad has happened."

and "EXC_BAD_ACCESS happens when a message is sent to an object that has already been released. By the time the error is caught, the call stack is usually gone especially if dealing with multiple threads."

Well, great.. but I don't how to fix it... Any help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning directly to `artworkInfo` (in `viewDidLoad`) instead of using the property accessor which would ensure that the array is properly retained. Your array is probably (auto)released by the time the table view datasource methods are called.

It should be:

```
self.artworkInfo = [[PaintingDatabase database] findAllArtists];
```

Answer (score 0):

If `NSLog(@"%d", rowsInDatabase);` is showing you the results you expect, then my suspicion is that artworkInfo is not being retained.  Assuming that you have declared it this way in your .h file (if it is an NSArray and not an NSMutableArray or something else):

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *artworkInfo;
```

Then the problem is probably that this line:

```
artworkInfo = [[PaintingDatabase database] findAllArtists];
```

Instead try changing it to:

```
self.artworkInfo = [[PaintingDatabase database] findAllArtists];
```

The difference is that the first line will assign the value of the variable directly, while the second actually runs it through a method called setArtworkInfo:, which although you can't see it, is automatically created when you use `@synthesize`.  Because the property declaration has `retain` in it, this method will also call the `retain` method on the object, so that it stays in memory after the end of the method.  Alternatively, you can do the same thing directly like this

```
artworkInfo = [[[PaintingDatabase database] findAllArtists] retain];
```

And make sure to add `[artworkInfo release]` in your dealloc method, because you should always call release on whatever objects you retain, when you are finished with them.